# Switch to another Git tag

Tags: git, github, git-tag

How do I check out version version/tag 1.1.4 of the [rspec bundle](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-tmbundle)?

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles/
git clone git://github.com/rspec/rspec-tmbundle.git RSpec.tmbundle
osascript -e 'tell app "TextMate" to reload bundles'
```

Answer (score 475, accepted):

Clone the repository as normal:

```
git clone git://github.com/rspec/rspec-tmbundle.git RSpec.tmbundle
```

Then checkout the tag you want like so:

```
git checkout tags/1.1.4
```

This will checkout out the tag in a 'detached HEAD' state. In this state, "you can look around, make experimental changes and commit them, and [discard those commits] without impacting any branches by performing another checkout".

To retain any changes made, move them to a new branch:

```
git checkout -b 1.1.4-jspooner
```

You can get back to the master branch by using:

```
git checkout master
```

Note, as was mentioned in the first revision of this answer, there is another way to checkout a tag:

```
git checkout 1.1.4
```

But as was mentioned in a comment, if you have a branch by that same name, this will result in git warning you that the refname is ambiguous and checking out the branch by default:

```
warning: refname 'test' is ambiguous.
Switched to branch '1.1.4'
```

The shorthand can be safely used if the repository does not share names between branches and tags.

Comment: For driveby viewers, this answer is ambiguous. If there's a branch and a tag called `1.1.4`. Git will checkout the branch, not the tag. To explicitly checkout the tag do: `git checkout tags/1.1.4`

Comment: How do we get back to the 'trunk'?

Comment: @VinayWadhwa git checkout master

Comment: And to see the tags, just issue `git tag`.

Answer (score 81):

As of [Git v2.23.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.23.0.txt) (August 2019), `git switch` is preferred over `git checkout` when you’re simply switching branches/tags. I’m guessing they did this since `git checkout` had two functions: for switching branches and for restoring files. So in v2.23.0, they added two new commands, `git switch`, and `git restore`, to separate those concerns. I would predict at some point in the future, `git checkout` will be deprecated.

To switch to a normal branch, use `git switch <branch-name>`. **To switch to a commit-like object, including single commits and tags**, use `git switch --detach <commitish>`, where `<commitish>` is the tag name or commit number.

The `--detach` option forces you to recognize that you’re in a mode of [“inspection and discardable experiments”](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---detach). To create a new branch from the commitish you’re switching to, use `git switch -c <new-branch> <start-point>`.

Comment: git switch supports switch to a branch. Switch to a tag is not supported.

Comment: `git switch --detach <tag>`  such as `git switch --detach v1.10` works quite well

Comment: @Progman , please see the 2nd paragraph of this answer.

Comment: As suggested in another answer, we'd better add the `tags` keyword, for instance `git switch --detach tags/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger-3.1.6.3`.

Answer (score 4):

[chharvey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/877703/chharvey)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60861134/6309) suggests

> To switch to a commit-like object, including single commits and tags, use `git switch --detach <commitish>`, where `<commitish>` is the tag name or commit number.

Actually, Git 2.36 (Q2 2022) is clearer: the error message given by "[`git switch  HEAD~4`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/061fd5727ddafe6a751303587cf80ca2f956a273/Documentation/git-switch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch))</sup>" has been clarified to suggest the "`--detach`" option that is required.

See [commit 808213b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/808213ba36ea72408cc45117a825ad9a714535ba) (25 Feb 2022) by [Alex Henrie (`alexhenrie`)](https://github.com/alexhenrie).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 061fd57](https://github.com/git/git/commit/061fd5727ddafe6a751303587cf80ca2f956a273), 06 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`switch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/808213ba36ea72408cc45117a825ad9a714535ba): mention the `--detach` option when dying due to lack of a branch
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Alex Henrie</sup>

> Users who are accustomed to doing [`git checkout <tag>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/808213ba36ea72408cc45117a825ad9a714535ba/Documentation/git-checkout.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout))</sup> assume that [`git switch <tag>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/808213ba36ea72408cc45117a825ad9a714535ba/Documentation/git-switch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch))</sup> will do the same thing.
> Inform them of the `--detach` option so they aren't left wondering why `git switch` doesn't work but `git checkout` does.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/808213ba36ea72408cc45117a825ad9a714535ba/Documentation/config/advice.txt#L88-L90):

> ### `suggestDetachingHead`
>
> Advice shown when [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) refuses to detach HEAD
> without the explicit `--detach` option.

The error message will show:

> ```
> a branch is expected, got tag 'xxx'
> If you want to detach HEAD at the commit, try again with the --detach option
> ```