# git: how to upgrade current changed workspace to a new release(tag) in github

Tags: git, github

git: how upgrade current changed workspace to a new release(tag) in github?

For example,

```
1. git clone a project at tag 1.0 in github
2. create a branch foo, and made some file changes
   in the branch, staged but not committed
3. the project has a new release 2.0
```

How to point to the new release 2.0 and pull all changes into the branch foo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch to another Git tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330610/switch-to-another-git-tag)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need to do is:

```
git fetch --tags
git checkout <destination_branch> //if not checked out
git merge <tag_name>
```

Hope this works for you!