# Git: If I've been working in detached head state for multiple commits, will I lose anything by getting out of it?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, git-checkout, git-detached-head

A while ago I checked out a previous commit, then checked out my most recent commit again. I didn't realize this at the time, but that left me in a detached head state. I've done multiple commits since then, and am still in the detached head state. I know I can get out of this state by doing `git checkout <branch name>`, but if I do this will I lose anything?

Answer (score 1):

> I can get out of this state by doing `git checkout <branch name>`, but if I do this will I lose anything?

Yes, you will lose all the commits you've made in detached head mode, because no branch name will be pointing to them. (You won't totally lose them immediately, but they will be slated for destruction, and accessing them will become more difficult.)

So simply create a branch first, to retain them and give you a way to refer to them.

```
git switch -c temp
```

Now it's safe to checkout `branchname`.

Actually in your case, though, since your HEAD is in fact where you wish your branch was, you can just move your branch name to where you are now instead. No need for `temp` at all.

```
git switch -C branchname
```

Comment: By the way, stop using git checkout and use git switch instead. That way you can never get into detached mode without knowing it.

Comment: I never heard of "git switch branch" before.  I'm not even sure how many of the git clients I have laying around on various lab machines even support it. Here's a good article: https://bluecast.tech/blog/git-switch-branch/

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't realize this at the time, but that left me in a detached head state

That is why I mention the more recent ([Git 2.23, Q3 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)) [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) command.

You cannot use `git switch <commit>` and *not* realize you end up in a detached HEAD state, because such a command would actually *fail*, with the error message:

```
fatal: a branch is expected, got <commitID>
If you want to detach HEAD at the commit, try again with the `--detach` option
```

See more at "[Why did my Git repo enter a detached HEAD state?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)".
The hint to use the `--detach` option [comes from Git 2.36 (Q2 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71428295/6309).